# Where to ask about Google app for iOS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to make sure I go to the right site. I have a question about a problem I'm having with the Google Wallet app for iOS. Which SE site would be best for this question?

Comment: The proper place would be Ask Different, but it also depends, on what your question is

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you should be OK at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). (Which I see you've already done.)

*Don't* ask at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). It seems that some think that anything "Google" goes there, but unless you're asking about the web interface, the question will get closed.